# How to get an Excel cell format number without comma when it's an integer and with two digit after comma when it's a float?

Tags: excel, cell-formatting

I work with Excel and I try to find a good format for my cell. I work with numbers that can have more than 10 digit behind comma and with integer. I want a format that can display an integer when it's a integer(without any comma and digit behind it) and display a number with two digit behind comma when it's a number with comma.

I know that "General" format can show an integer as Integer and Number with comma as a number with comma, but this doesn't work because you can choose to get the only 2 first digit behind the comma in "General" format, you have to take all digit.

So here's my format for now `General;General;""` I can try this too `0,00;-0,00;""` but this format ignore integer

PS: When I talk about number with comma I talking about float number not number that are separated with comma due to 1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such format :-(

As kind of a hack, you could apply a conditional formatting.

As base numberformat use `0,00;-0,00;""`

Plus apply the following conditional formatting:

- Formula: `=A1=ROUNDDOWN(A1,0)`   i.e: = integer
- Numberformat = `0;-0;""`

Comment: A little bit tricky but very clever. If there is an update or another solution that come in your minde don't hesitate to edit your answer and add a new way to do it :) ! Thanks a lot